# The Windows Form background is OK on development, but is white on production

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tabs, windows-forms-designer, groupbox

I am developing in Visual Studio with Windows Forms on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard, and when I want to run on Windows 10, I see a bug in the backcolor.
I use TabPages, into each page I have a DataGridView and some elements, and the problem is only on index=0. This change its backcolor to white, and I don't know why (but into the GroupBoxes or PictureBoxes not does).

I put a capture:

[current version bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vfx3z.png)

But when I am developing on the server, I see it well:

[current version running ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDas2.png)

Someone know what can be it?

Thanks!

**This is the Main code on Program.cs:**

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        bool activo;
        System.Threading.Mutex mutex = new System.Threading.Mutex(true, "SistemaDePagos", out activo);

        if (!activo)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ya hay una instancia de la aplicación abierta.", "Sistema de Pagos - SIDOM S.A.");
            Application.Exit();
        }
        else
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new FormPresentacion()); // FormPresentacion
        }
        // Liberamos la exclusión mutua
        mutex.ReleaseMutex();
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you're using different themes. Did you call `Application.EnableVisualStyles()` in your WinForm?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, I called. I put the code fragment in the publication.